# Android Studio Navigation Drawer template error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

It must be a very stupid mistake, but I cannot seem to figure it out. In Android Studio 2.3.3, when I create a new app and select first activity as Navigation Drawer Activity, everything works fine.

But when I create another activity from Navigation Drawer template, the .xml files are different and so the code of the activity, which results in `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class fragment` error when the activity is launched.

I tried to create the activity by right-clicking on `app` and `res`, but the result is still the same.

Am I missing something basic?

Comment: post layout.xml and your fragment code here

Comment: The code? I might do that, the problem is, I didn't edit even a line.

Answer (score 0):

import android.app.Fragment;

to:

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

Comment: Didn't work, there are a lot more differences between activity created with project and one added later.